# How to install pytorch with CUDA support with pip in Visual Studio

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to install `torch with CUDA enabled` in Visual Studio environment. I right clicked on **Python Environments** in Solution Explorer, uninstalled the existing version of Torch that is not compiled with CUDA and tried to run this `pip command` from the official `Pytorch` website. The command is:

`pip3 install torch==1.10.0+cu102 torchvision==0.11.1+cu102 torchaudio===0.10.0+cu102 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html`

Visual Studio reports this error `Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3`.

I have seen similar questions asked on this site but some are circumventing on `Conda` while others did have unclear answers which were not accepted so I was in doubt whether to follow the answers or not. I have a very important project I need to present and I can't do that unless I install torch with cuda enabled, Please Help me and Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

I followed [the main instructions for installing on pytorch's site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) but still failed to have success.  For my setup this resulted in `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117`.

I had to add `--upgrade --force-reinstall` which *finally* fixed the problem.

Comment: I will test and let you know it it works.

Comment: Perfect. Worked without the force for me. Thanks!

Comment: After 5 hours searching for something, installing torch multiple times, 3 different versions of CUDA this is the command that finally worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

You can check in the [pytorch previous versions website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/). First, make sure you have cuda in your machine by using the `nvcc --version` command

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 4):

+cu117I still kept having the same problem until adding --no-cache-dir, pip kept installing another cached version. The following command solved the problem for me. Had to use == for torch version and >= for torchvision and torchaudio because there isn't a package that contains 1.13.1, 0.13.1, 0.13.1 with cu117

```
pip3 install torch==1.13.1+cu117 torchvision>=0.13.1+cu117 torchaudio>=0.13.1+cu117 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117 --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 3):

This line of code worked for me in anaconda and windows11:

```
pip install torch>=1.13.0+cu116 torchvision>=0.13.0+cu116 torchaudio>=0.13.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue in my windows machine, and this is what worked for me:

1. Uninstalled the old pytorch that has no cuda - `pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio`
2. Installed afresh, with cuda support - `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118`

Comment: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121 works as well.